# How can I get my table to join with null or blank values?

Tags: sql, join

I am using the following query to join 2 tables

```
SELECT TOP (20000) 
      [AHC] 
      ,[itinerary]
      ,[PnrLocator]
      ,[hotelSabre] 
      ,[sabre]
  FROM [totaldw].[dbo].[Travel_Fct] tf
 inner join [ETL_Gooddata].[ETL].[GHCAnalysis] gh
  on tf.hotelsabre = gh.sabre 
    where tf.hotelsabre = gh.sabre
```

where [totaldw].[dbo].[Travel_Fct] will have values for hotelsabre that [ETL_Gooddata].[ETL].[GHCAnalysis] does not necessarily have. If there is not a sabre value that matches with the hotelsabre value, I am looking for a blank or null to appear, but instead the join is only providing record where there is a match. I tried some variations of

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Sabre FROM [ETL_Gooddata].[ETL].[GHCAnalysis] gh WHERE Sabre = hotelSabre)
```

versus joining the tables, but have not been able to get it to work.

How can I get the sabre column to populate for every record in [totaldw].[dbo].[Travel_Fct] with blank or null for those that do not have a match?

Comment: Hi, you do know you don't have to quote those names, right?  `totaldw.dbo.Travel_Fct` is a perfectly fine name without the extra brackets.  SQL is much easier to read and use when you drop unneeded quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `left join`:

```
FROM [totaldw].[dbo].[Travel_Fct] tf LEFT JOIN
     [ETL_Gooddata].[ETL].[GHCAnalysis] gh
     ON tf.hotelsabre = gh.sabre
```

And remove the redundant `WHERE` clause.